# Rails asset_path hangs in IntegrationTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets, livelock

In an `.html.erb` file, I have `<img src=<%= asset_path "logo.png" %> >` and it works fine on the page. I have an integration test that renders this ERB file, and when it gets to rendering that line, the test hangs and the processor usage goes to 100% on one core.

Is this a sprockets bug? Is it likely that I have something else out of place?

Edit: Here's my test:

```
test 'index' do
  log_in_as(@user, 'pass')
  trans = get transactions_path
end
```

Comment: Can you please add the test to the question? Does this happen only with this asset?

Comment: @max Thanks for asking. I added the test to the question. I have only written two tests: the one above and `test 'create'`. The latter works fine (`post transactions_path params: { transaction: 'hey' }`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Gemfile, don't use `sass-rails`. Back then it didn't, but now it issues a "deprecated" warning imploring you to use a different sass implementation. I switched to `sassc-rails` to good effect on my project, but you may have to do some research to find a suitable replacement.